# How to change what object information is called for in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a text based RPG.  The problem I'm facing is that I want individual enemy values, i.e. goblins, orcs, etc., but I don't know how to allow a function to grab information from a specific class object for individual situations.  I may be wording this horribly; my apologies.  To use an example:  If I have an individual combat function that is called each time a user enters a room with an enemy in it, how do I go about differentiating between what enemy information the function should call based on the room.

Could I use an enemy variable?  Say, when a specific room function is called, and the room has an enemy in it, a global variable named enemy could change, and somehow allow the combat function to retrieve information based on the variable information.  In other words, if a player enters a room with a goblin, the function would change the global variable to 'goblin'.  Is there a way for python to look at that variable and say 'Oh!  He wants to load the data for the goblin object!"?

Here is a basic version of my code:

```
enemy = ' '
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

def room():
    print("You walk into a room and see a goblin.  You enter combat. ")
    enemy = goblin.name
    combat()

def combat():
    dieroll = random.randint(1, 20)
    attack = raw_input("Press [A] to attack.: ").lower()
    while attack:
        if attack == 'a':

            #Here is where I want the function to retrieve information from an
            #enemy object, to determine its name, health, and damage.  

            print("You did", dieroll, "damage to" #enemy name)
            #lower enemy health



goblin = enemy('goblin', 100, 15)
```

I hope some of this is making sense, even if the code is a bit sloppy, even though my idea for a solution might be a silly one.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Usually you have one base enemy class that offers all the functions and subclass that inherit the base with the special attributes of the type. If you want to go more data driven, you have one class and a data structure that defines the attributes of the types. This could be a dict of dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a bunch of functions and calling each one at the end of the previous one, use functions to structure your code. You can hard-code a few things for now, but eventually you'll want some kind of loop that will move the game along until it ends.

Functions should know as little about their surrounding environment as possible - generally, you'll pass external data into the function, do some kind of calculation, and return values. As `room()` relies on the creation of `goblin`, that function will break if you decide to create a different kind of enemy, or create enemies later, or simply have an empty room. Instead, pass in any enemies and objects for the function to work with.

`combat()` would make more sense here if it accepted parameters of combatants, modifying them and then returning some result to the calling function. Here's an example:

```
class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage

def room(player, enemy=None):
    print "You walk into a room...",
    if enemy:
        print " and see a {}. You enter combat.".format(enemy.name)
        if combat(enemy, player):
            print 'You gain 3 experience.'
            player.xp += 3 # just for example
    else:
        print "there's nothing here."

def combat(enemy, player):
    attack = raw_input("Press [A] to attack.: ").lower()
    while attack and player.health:
        if attack == 'a':
            dieroll = random.randint(1, 20)
            player.health = max(player.health-dieroll, 0)
            print enemy.name, 'did', dieroll, 'damage to you!'
            dieroll = random.randint(1, 20)
            enemy.health -= dieroll
            print "You did", dieroll, "damage to", enemy.name)
    return player.health # just for example

player = Player('jim', 90, 18) # maybe make a Player class
goblin = enemy('goblin', 100, 15)
room(player, goblin)
```

Also note that I've corrected the `print` statements to actually be Python 2-style `print` statements. Unless you're importing the Python 3 `print()` function, things like `print("You did", dieroll, "damage to" #enemy name)` will print a `tuple`, producing something like:

```
('You did', 14, 'damage to', 'goblin')
```

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for the reply.  This is a project from a long time ago when I first barely got into Python, so I'm looking to finish it up.  The Python 3 stuff is there on accident.  I originally learned Python as a 3.x variant, but I have recently set up an old laptop as an Ubuntu rig, where Python 2.7 is installed, so I got a bit mixed up -- I'm still transitioning haha.  

I don't know why I didn't think of adding an argument to the combat function.  That is basic knowledge that you can define arguments of functions when you call them.  

I appreciate the help thank you!